# use multidimension array cart session to take form hidden to valid a order

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, hidden-field

I try to save the cart array to finish the order and take then dates from the customer about  him order. I made something but doesnt work well, firstly is showing me on page `confirm_comanda.php` the array dates for the last array to say for exemple I have in the cart session 3 products, is taking me the `product_name` `price` for the last array prodcuts. Only the `quanty` is showing me well, and the final price called `totalCOMANDApret`

```
// Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        // start select query stmt
        $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price, size, details FROM products WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($idSelect, $product_name, $price, $size, $details);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
        while ($stmt->fetch())    {
           $idSelect;
           $product_name; // faci acelasi lucru fara $row 
           $price;    
           $size;
           $details;    
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        // stoop select stmt    
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
                // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="100" height="62" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $price . ' RON</td>';
        // How to split a query value into several mutiple rows for a select tag using explode() STAART SIZE
        $myArraySize = explode(' ',  $size);
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><select name="size">';
        foreach($myArraySize as $my_ArraySize)
        {
        $cartOutput .= '<option  value="'.$my_ArraySize.'">'.$my_ArraySize.'</option>';
        }
        $cartOutput .= '</select><input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />buc
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //STOP SIZE
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><center>' . $pricetotal . ' RON</center></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
```

the form hidden which supossed to take the session array dates from the produts selected in the cart array

```
$cofirmaComanda = '<form  action="cofirma_comanda.php" method="post">';
            $i=0;
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { //start second forecach

            $cofirmaComanda .='
            <input name="prettotal[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $pricetotal .'">
            <input name="produseID[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
            <input name="produseNume[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
            <input name="size[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $my_ArraySize .'">
            <input name="cantitate[]"  type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] .'">
            <input name="produse[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">;
            <input name="totalCOMANDApret[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $cartTotal .'">';
                } //close second foreach
            $cofirmaComanda .='<input type="submit" name="CofirmaComanda" value="cofirma_comandaTOW"></form>';  
        }
```

the page confirm_comanda.php to valid the order and take customer billing dates and shipping

```
$countArray = count($_SESSION['cart_array']);
for ($i=0; $i<$countArray; $i++) {
    $pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"][$i];
    $PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"][$i];
    $produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"][$i];
    $size = $_POST["size"][$i];
    $cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"][$i];
    $total = $_POST["totalCOMANDApret"][$i];
}
```

form hidden and form input for finish the order

```
<form action="confirma_comanda2.php"   method="post">
<tr><td>nume: <input name="nume_client" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr><td>email: <input name="email_client" type="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>telefon: <input name="telefon_client" type="number"></td></tr>
<tr><td>judet: <select name="judet_client">
<option value="Arges">Arges</option>
<option value="Arad">Arad</option>
<option value="Timis">Timis</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>adresa: <input name="adresa_client" type="text"></td></tr>
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$countArray; $i++) {
    $confirmForm =' <input type="hidden" name="prettotal" value=" echo '.$pretTotal[$i].'">
<input type="hidden" name="produse" value=" echo '.$PRODUSE.'">
<input type="hidden" name="produseNume" value=" echo'.$produseNume.'">
<input type="hidden" name="cantitate" value=" echo'.$cantitate.'">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value=" echo'.$size.'">
<input type="hidden" name="totalComanda" value="'.$total.'">';
}
?> 
<tr><td><input  type="submit" name="sumbitDateClienti" value="Trimite Comanda"></td><td><input type="button" onClick="location.href='index.php';" value="Inapoi la Cumparaturi">
```

I know is a whole code but i realy want to fix this problem, a part of the script was taking from an online course, but there they used paypal, I changed that because i want to make it more simple

Comment: Please anyone? can give me a answer? sorry to double post